# Create a Map and pass values to it at the same time in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

You can create a Map in JavaScript and add a value to it like so:

```
const myMap = new Map();
myMap.set('foo', 'bar');
console.log({myMap});
```

However can you create a new Map and add values to it on one line? Something like this:

```
const myMap2 = new Map({'foo':'bar'});
console.log({myMap2});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an array of key-value pairs to the `Map` constructor

```js
const myMap = new Map([['foo', 'bar'], ['baz', 'value']])
console.log({ myMap });
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the [official documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) the Map object accepts an iterable i.e.

```
new Map([iterable])
```

So, you will not be able to do it one line. Instead you can pass an array of key value pairs as @adiga mentioned in his answer.